# how to reference an expression from the previous list value in sql?

Tags: sql, select, sum, percentage

So I'm not sure if I explained my question correctly in the title but I'll try saying it here. Let's say you have a table like this

[image]

How can you, in a single query, add up the grades and create a new column showcasing each row's percent of total grades like this:

[image]

I've tried doing something like

```sql
Select SUM( Grade) As total, Grade/total as Percent total
```

but it doesn't seem to work this way. I know I can obviously do two queries one for the sum and then make it happen directly. Can anyone tell help me do the percent total in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function. For example:

```
select *, 100 * grade / sum(grade) over() as percent_total from t
```

Comment: @GalaxyS . . . This is definitely the better solution although in some databases, you might need `* 100.0` to avoid integer division.

Answer (score 1):

You could cross-join this query with a query that returns a single row of the sum:

```sql
SELECT     t.*, 100 * t.grade / s.sum_grades AS "Percent Total"
FROM       mytable t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(grade) AS sum_grades
            FROM   mytable) s
```